I have 2 data frames to compare but the columns are slightly different
I wish to compare the following 2 data frames to check against the second one to see if any of my values are higher. The main issue here is that the columns have slightly different names. For reference my data frame look like;
myDat
firstA firstB secondA secondB thirdA  thirdB    
   13     4      40        24    16      10

comparisonDat
first second third
  18    35     8

My end goal is to compare the data frames by comparing 'firstA' and 'firstB' to 'first' and so on in my comparisonDat to check they are not a higher value and if they are return a subset of my data like so below as these are the values that are hhigher;
myDat_comparison
secondA thirdA  thirdB
  40      16      10

I feel like this can be done in a simple which statement something along the lines of myDat[which(myDat > comparisonDat),] if my column names were to match up. Im not really sure how to fix this, I guess the easiest way would be to gsub() the A and B versions out of my data although im not sure that would work and it wouldn't allow me to identify after

Are you trying to compare column totals or row by row? Also, can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset? Would make it easier to help - guide if you need one https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

Assuming each column in comparisonDat has single values, convert myDat to long format and filter values based on the columns from comparisonDat. Then convert the filtered data back to wide format.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

myDat |> 
  rename_with(.fn=function(x) gsub("(\\w+)([AB])", "\\1_\\2", x), .cols=everything()) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols=everything(), names_to="var", values_to="value") |> 
  separate_wider_delim(cols=var, delim="_", names=c("group", "letter")) |> 
  filter(case_when(
    group == "first" ~ value > comparisonDat$first,
    group == "second" ~ value > comparisonDat$second,
    group == "third" ~ value > comparisonDat$third
  )) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(group, letter), values_from=value, names_sep="")

# A tibble: 1 × 3
  secondA thirdA thirdB
    <int>  <int>  <int>
1      40     16     10

data
myDat <- read.table(text="firstA firstB secondA secondB thirdA  thirdB    
   13     4      40        24    16      10", header=TRUE)
comparisonDat <- read.table(text="first second third
  18    35     8", header=TRUE)



1) Here is a purrr solution.  For each name in comparisonDat find the corresponding columns in myDat and then use keep to filter that down to the ones satisfying the inequality.
library(purrr)

map_dfc(names(comparisonDat), ~ {
  keep(myDat[grep(.x, names(myDat))], \(x) x > comparisonDat[.x])
})
##   secondA thirdA thirdB
## 1      40     16     10

2) In base R it is similar.  Use Filter instead of keep and do.call("cbind", lapply(...)) instead of map_dfc.
do.call("cbind", lapply(names(comparisonDat), \(.x) {
  Filter(\(x) x > comparisonDat[.x], myDat[grep(.x, names(myDat))])
}))
##   secondA thirdA thirdB
## 1      40     16     10

Note
The input data in reproducible form:
comparisonDat <- data.frame(first = 18L, second = 35L, third = 8L)
myDat <- data.frame(firstA = 13L, firstB = 4L, secondA = 40L, secondB = 24L,
  thirdA = 16L, thirdB = 10L)

